# MVC.NET web app error on published site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, web-hosting

So I am trying to finish up my first MVC.NET(in c#) app, and I've published my website through godaddy's plesk panel. I've downloaded my publishing profile from plesk, and imported it to my VS project.

The publish didn't give any errors in VS, but it did freeze and become unresponsive for a couple of minutes when i clicked anywhere on the publish dialog box. There were also a bunch of little white dashes going all across the screen that only went away when I hovered over them with my mouse. I'm not sure if any of that is related to the real issue I'm having though.

When I try to load my home page on the live site all I see are the things from my shared layout (nav bar, header, footer, etc), and this text "Error. An error occurred while processing your request." The only pages that do load properly are the pages that are included when you create a MVC.NET app (login, register, manage, etc.) All of my pages did load properly when i previewed them from my local project.

I have published this site before (a long time ago) and it all loaded properly, however it would take an insane amount of time (generally 2-5 minutes) to load or even refresh a page. The login/manage pages that do currently load are still taking this long to load.

I tried creating and publishing a test-app with just the default pages, and it worked perfectly fine. No freezing issues during publishing, everything displayed properly, and the load times were normal.

I am definitely in over my head with this project, as I have very little experience in this field. Any and all advice is appreciated.

Comment: First of all, it is hard to give you an "answer" on this topic. You're better off taking this to a forum with a community that is willing to help you troubleshoot. Here is one little piece of advice that will hopefully go a long way though: you might be seeing the default custom error page for an MVC project. Check out this link to enable detailed error messages from the server:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rakkimk/2007/05/25/iis7-how-to-enable-the-detailed-error-messages-for-the-website-while-browsed-from-for-the-client-browsers/

Comment: If possible, you might want to SFTP or use the file manager from GoDaddy to ensure that all of your files were properly copied. Also make sure to look at your log files, a more detailed error message may be available that will point you in the right direction.